# Project needs to be compiled twice to copy files

Tags: qt, build, qmake

I've created with QT creator a project, and I've modified manually the qmakefile. The problem is that, when I modify something, I need to build the project two times because the first time I've some post-link copy problem. The first time the compilation output says, at the end of compilation (that ends successfully):

```
cp ../../../configuration/options.xml ../../../bin cp /usr/lib/MyFramework/Debug/libMyFramework.so ../../../bin cp /usr/lib/MyFramework/Debug/libMyFrameworkRoutines.so ../../../bin
cp: omitting directory `../../../bin'
cp: cannot stat `cp': No such file or directory
cp: omitting directory `../../../bin'
cp: cannot stat `cp': No such file or directory
```

while the second time it compiles correctly and I've not this problem.

My makefile is like the following

```
# Variables used in the project
SOURCES_PATH     = $$quote(../../../src/UpdateManager/sources)
HEADERS_PATH     = $$quote(../../../src/UpdateManager/headers)
DESTINATION_PATH = $$quote(../../../bin)

# Project configuration
QT       -= gui
TARGET    = UpdateManager
TEMPLATE  = lib
DEFINES  += UPDATEMANAGER_LIBRARY

# Copying to destination folder
DESTDIR = $$DESTINATION_PATH

# Headers paths used in the project
INCLUDEPATH += $$HEADERS_PATH

# Source files
SOURCES += \
    ../../../src/UpdateManager/sources/options.cpp \
    ../../../src/UpdateManager/sources/consolelog.cpp \
    ../../../src/UpdateManager/sources/updatemanager.cpp

HEADERS += \
    ../../../src/UpdateManager/headers/options.h \
    ../../../src/UpdateManager/headers/consolelog.h \
    ../../../src/UpdateManager/headers/updatemanager.h

OTHER_FILES += \
    ../../../configuration/options.xml

unix:!symbian {
    maemo5 {
        target.path = /opt/usr/lib
    } else {
        target.path = /usr/lib
    }
    INSTALLS += target
}

### EXTERNAL LIBRARIES ###

# my framework
MY_FRAMEWORK_HEADERS_PATH = $$quote(/usr/include/MyFramerork/)
MY_FRAMEWORK_LIBRARY_PATH = $$quote(/usr/lib/MyFramerork)
MY_FRAMEWORK_ROUTINES_HEADERS_PATH    = $$quote(/usr/include/MyFramerork/routines)

INCLUDEPATH += $$MY_FRAMEWORK_HEADERS_PATH
INCLUDEPATH += $$MY_FRAMEWORK_ROUTINES_HEADERS_PATH

LIBS += -L$$MY_FRAMEWORK_LIBRARY_PATH/Debug/ -lMyFramework
LIBS += -L$$MY_FRAMEWORK_LIBRARY_PATH/Debug/ -lMyFrameworkRoutines

# Copying needed files in out directory
unix{
  EXTERNAL_FILES += \
    ../../../configuration/options.xml \
    $$MY_FRAMEWORK_LIBRARY_PATH/Debug/libMyFramework.so \
    $$MY_FRAMEWORK_LIBRARY_PATH/Debug/libMyFrameworkRoutines.so

  for(FILE,EXTERNAL_FILES){
    QMAKE_POST_LINK += $$quote(cp $${FILE} $${DESTDIR})
  }
}

# Boost
LIBS += -lboost_thread
```

I think that the copy problem is related to this section

```
# Copying needed files in out directory
unix{
  EXTERNAL_FILES += \
    ../../../configuration/options.xml \
    $$MY_FRAMEWORK_LIBRARY_PATH/Debug/libMyFramework.so \
    $$MY_FRAMEWORK_LIBRARY_PATH/Debug/libMyFrameworkRoutines.so

  for(FILE,EXTERNAL_FILES){
    QMAKE_POST_LINK += $$quote(cp $${FILE} $${DESTDIR})
  }
}
```

Because in this section I copy files that give me problem in the output. All dir exists. So where am I wrong and how can I correct it so files are correctly copied in first build step?

Thanks in advance for your replies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I am not wrong any directory specified by `DESTDIR` will be created if it doesn't already exists. On the other hand you cannot be sure that this happens after the linking of the target is over.

So you should add

```
QMAKE_POST_LINK += mkdir -p $${DESTINATION_PATH}
for(FILE,EXTERNAL_FILES){
   QMAKE_POST_LINK += && $$quote(cp $${FILE} $${DESTDIR})
}
```

to create the target directory first and copy upon success.

**EDITED:** There was a mistake. Without a logical command operator like && (use what is more appropriate) it considers the following commands as
arguments of `mkdir`.

Comment: I've just done it, but nothing happens. Compiler adds a warning telling that it cannot creates directory because it already exists.

    mkdir: cannot create directory `../../../configuration/options.xml': File exists
    mkdir: cannot create directory `/usr/lib/awframework/Debug/libMyFramework.so': File exists
    mkdir: cannot create directory `/usr/lib/awframework/Debug/libMyFrameworkRoutines.so': File exists

Comment: It works, thanks! The only modification to your solution was to write  `QMAKE_POST_LINK += mkdir -p $${DESTINATION_PATH}`  instead of    `QMAKE_POST_LINK = mkdir -p $${DESTINATION_PATH}`